# Excel to json, if value the same - sum it python

Tags: python, json, openpyxl

I have .xlsx file with data.

[image: screenshot]

I need to make json file from .xlsx.
In future this json will be used in func of TG_bot. Bot will ask user "Which brand?" - "BQQ", "Which name?" - "C", "Which month?" - "November 2020" and the bot gives user price and summ.

I made smth like this.. but it doesn't work correctly
Also it can be duplicates in device_name, and if it is script have to sum up their device_price and device_summ (only if month are the same)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import json

wb = load_workbook('data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
maxrows = ws.max_row
print(maxrows)

data = {}

for i in range(2, maxrows):



    device_name = ws[f'A{i}'].value
    device_brand = ws[f'B{i}'].value
    device_price_usd = ws[f'C{i}'].value
    device_summ_usd = ws[f'D{i}'].value
    month = ws[f'E{i}'].value

    datetime_date = month
    date_object = datetime_date.date()
    string_date = date_object.isoformat()
    if string_date == "2020-10-01":
        string_date = "oct_2020"
    elif string_date == "2020-11-01":
        string_date = "nov_2020"


    data[i] = {
        # "device_name": device_name,
        "device_brand": device_brand,
        "device_price_uah": device_price_uah,
        "device_price_usd": device_price_usd,
        "device_summ_uah": device_summ_uah,
        "device_summ_usd": device_summ_usd,
        "month": string_date,
        "number": i

    }




with open("data.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, default=str)

    enter code here
```

Help plz )

Answer (score 0):

i think if you use pandas for this work, it is very easy:
you can use the something like the below code:

```
import pandas

excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('records.xlsx', sheet_name='Employees')

json_str = excel_data_df.to_json()

print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', json_str)
```

this code get from this url :https://www.journaldev.com/33335/python-excel-to-json-conversion

in the above url talk about python package called "excel2json-3", you can also use this to convert excel to json.
this is pypi address: https://pypi.org/project/excel2json-3/

Comment: You didn't read my full message...

Comment: if you explain what you want exactly, then I can help you in a  desirable manner. all that i understand is this, you want to convert a excel to a json.

Comment: Isn't that clearly explained?)

I need to make json file from .xlsx. In future this json will be used in func of TG_bot. Bot will ask user "Which brand?" - "BQQ", "Which name?" - "C", "Which month?" - "November 2020" and the bot gives user price and summ.

I made smth like this.. but it doesn't work correctly Also it can be duplicates in device_name, and if it is script have to sum up their device_price and device_summ (only if month are the same)

Comment: 'Script have to sum up their device_price and device_summ (only if month are the same)'